# Backbone script to read from external JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I want to display data from JSON using a backbone script.

This is the html Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="backbone.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend();
var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Profile,
    url: 'document.json'
});

var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#profiles",
    template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.collection,"add", this.renderItem);          
    },
    render: function () {
        this.collection.each(function(model){
             var profileTemplate = this.template(model.toJSON());
             this.$el.append(profileTemplate);
        }, this);        
        return this;
    },
    renderItem: function(profile) {
         var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());
         this.$el.append(profileTemplate);        
    }


});

var profileList = new ProfileList();
var profilesView = new ProfileView({ collection: profileList });
profilesView.render();



});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="profiles"></div>

<script id="profileTemplate" type="text/template">
<div class="profile">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="name">
                <%= name %>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <%= title %>
            </div>
            <div class="background">
                <%= background %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                <br />
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my json data:
document.json

```
[
{
    "id": "p1",        
    "name" : "AAAA",
    "title" : "BBBB",
    "background" : "CCCC"
},
{
    "id": "p2",
    "name" : "DDDD",
    "title" : "EEEE",
    "background" : "FFFF"
},
{
    "id": "p3",        
    "name" : "GGGG",
    "title" : "HHHH",
    "background" : "IIII"
}
]
```

There's nothing being displayed on the page.
Am I missing something?
I have been trying to get the JSON data printed on the div element in specified HTML. But Nothing being displayed. I tried debugging the code, I could insert alert statement before **Backbone.Model.extend** inside **document.ready** in jquery. But when I put alert statement inside it, it isnt coming up. So, the code inside **Backbone.Model.extend** must be gone wrong somewhere.
Somebody help me?

Comment: Any errors in console? Was request actually made?

Comment: What's the scope of 'this' within the each loop of the render method?

Comment: Check the order of loading your scripts, jquery should come first then backbone.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko 
I didnt get any error in console 
I fixed my issue. it was browser issue!
dont know why its working on firefox and not working in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the order of loading your scripts, jquery should come first, underscore secondly (since you are using undescore.js templating) then backbone:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If that doesn't solve your problem then you could either try sending in a static reference to your initial set of data, then call fetch() as needed to grab more, or you can call fetch explicitly as follows:

```
var profileList = new ProfileList();    
var profilesView = new ProfileView({collection: profileList});
profileList.fetch();
profileList.bind('reset', function () {
   profilesView.render();
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/y8ZWm/)

Comment: At the end I updated the code:


    `var profileList = new ProfileList();
 var profilesView = new ProfileView({ collection: profileList     });
 profileList.fetch();
 profileList.bind('reset', function () {
    profilesView.render();
 });`

Comment: Did that update work? Also did you fix the order of loading your scripts i.e. jquery > underscore > backbone?

Comment: I have also changed the order..This is the new code: 
[jsonbackbone](http://chopapp.com/#o14e7vfv)

Comment: I did as you told, and attached a link to my new source code just above.
can you have a look on it?

Comment: This is not a separate .json though, this is storing the json as a variable. How would you do it in a separate .json file?

I tried redirecting var document = 'jsonSample.json', but it did not work.

Comment: @Aspen You need to put it as the collection's url property value like `var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Profile, url: 'jsonSample.json' });`

Answer (score 0):

You should load scripts in order, jquery, underscore and then Backbone